# User always creating files with 640 permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, raspbian

**Short introduction**: I'm fairly new to Unix-Systems and got a Raspberry 3b+ using it as a Web-Server. Obviously I'm using a different computer for development and transfer the files via sftp. Always running into permission-problems after file transfers I checked my ftp-server (proftpd) for problems (umask) and noticed that whatever the umask in the config nothing changes in the actual file permissions, not even when i change the umask to 777. I got a hint of looking into user-umasks which I then persued and led meto something which i think is the actual problem.

**Problem**: I'm currently using the standard "pi" user. Whenever i create a file (doesn't matter if i use touch in bash or rightclick - new in file manager) in any directory (for testing purposes i used /home/pi/Desktop/) it's created with 640 permissions.

What i checked:

- umask command: says 022, changing to 000 results in file created with 660 permissions
- /etc/profile: no umask there (i also learned it's the wrong place, but early search led me there)
- /etc/login.defs: has umask set to 022
- /etc/pam.d/: no umask set in any file
- .bashrc: no umask set

Can anyone tell me what i can do so files get created with 644 permissions?

If i'm missing something obvious bonus-thanks if you explain how i could've googled it myself.

Comment: Are ACL's being used ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i'm using the standard installation, please tell me how to check that

Comment: See my second answer.

Comment: Probably the wrong place too, but there's also /etc/profile.d/.

Comment: What filesystem would this be?   Can you add the output of "mount" ?

Comment: I can't tell you the file system, i'm new, the OS is Raspbian.
i checked /etc/profile.d/ bow and there is no entry about umask in any file

Comment: Please add the output of "mount" to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Set Umask 022 in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

```
Umask 022 022
```

The second 022 is for directories.

Comment: tried that, no change, tried setting it to 777 777 also no change, the problem isn't with proftpd

Comment: You did restart proftpd?

Comment: yes i restarted proftpd and to make sure i didn't f* that up i restarted the whole raspberry

Answer (score 0):

Check if one of the parent directories has an ACL (access control list).  An "ls -l" will show a "+" if that is the case, as in:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 ghp  ghp  4096 Apr 26 19:23 .
```

Check the ACL, if there is a "default":

```
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: ghp
# group: ghp
user::rwx
user:pi:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rw-
default:other::---
```

Comment: i did an ls -l on he directory, it shows drwr-xr-x on folders that i already had in (and chmod to be ok) and on the new created file it says -rw-r--r--

Comment: Go one level up to verify the directory itself, or use "ls -ald ."  And that for each parent directory too.

Comment: ls -ald says drwxr-xr-x 5 pi pi 4096 Apr 26 17:57

Comment: I found one more possibility.  See my third answer.

Answer (score 0):

I promise to give up after this one:

Your problem is not caused by proftpd, but by sftp-server.

Did you disable

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config?   You can set the umask of sftp-server with the -u option.

Comment: you've given up even before you proposed your answer... read the "problem"-part... ANY user creates files with 640 even the pi logged in directly.. and it's not ssh related because it's the same for local user

Comment: I'm almost out of ideas.